# Create variable while in VS Code C/C++ debug console

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger, gdbserver

While debugging the main function in Debug Console, I want to create a new variable called 'b' and assign a integer value 9 to it, but it compalins about 'b' being undefined. Why am I getting this error and how can I get around it?

```
-> int b = 9;
   identifier "b" is undefined
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0; 
    printf("i is %d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gdb in general, you can define [convenience variables](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html) like so:

```
set $b = 9
```

in order to do this from the Debug Console, you must use the `-exec` prefix:

```
-exec set $b = 9
```

and you can then write lines like

```
-exec p i + $b
```

(where `i` is your C variable).

---

In picture:

[image]

and you can even use these convenience variables in places like the Watch interface:

[image]